# Radon-Nikodym derivative of Lebesgue measure with respect to Hausdorff measure is Jacobian term?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, haar-measure, hausdorff-measure

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. I have a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined as the level set of a *smooth* function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$
$$
\mathcal{M} = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = 0\right\}
$$
This submanifold is $n - m$ dimensional and is embedded in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Hausdorff measure on this manifold.

> What is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the Lebesgue measure with respect to the Hausdorff measure?
> $$
> \frac{d\lambda}{d\mathcal{H}} = ?
> $$

#### Attempted Solution

Intuitively, I would guess this is the "jacobian term"
$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\mathcal{H}}(x) = \left|J_f(x) J_f(x)^\top\right|^{1/2}
$$
where $J_f(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$. However I was not able to prove this. To be honest, I am not sure how generally one goes about finding a Radon-Nikodym derivative. What's the strategy one uses, given the two measures?

I know that the definition is
$$
\lambda(A) = \int_A \frac{d \lambda}{d \mathcal{H}} d\mathcal{H}
$$

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert in measures so maybe that is why, but it is not clear to me what the Lebesgue measure would be on your manifold if it is not the Hausdorff measure. Any definition that I have seen of a Lebesgue measure on a manifold coincides with the Hausdorff measure (of the appropriate dimension of course), for any reasonable metric on the manifold (see for instance https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380247/equality-of-hausdorff-measure-and-lebesgue-measure-on-manifolds-reference ).

Comment: @CaptainLama I think you're right! The Hausdorff measure $d\mathcal{H}$ should be equivalent to the Lebesgue measure $d\lambda^{n-m}$ (the $n-m$ dimensional Lebesgue measure). Then I suppose the question is:


What is the Radon-Nikodym derivative between these two Lebesgue measures?

Comment: Could you remind me of the definition of the Lebesgue measure on a manifold?

Comment: @Jonas mmmh I'm not sure. I think if the manifold has dimension $n$ then the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure would be equivalent to the Lebesgue measure.